# need query for desired output in mysql db

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables ITEM and CONDITION with below db structure

```
ITEM => 
    ID - INTEGER
    ITEM_NAME - VARCHAR

CONDITION => 
    CID - INTEGER
    COND_NAME  - VARCHAR
    ITEM_ARRAY - VARCHAR (Stores all ITEM ID's separated by space 
                      like: 1 5 9 17 18

CID  COND_NAME  IEM_ARRAY

1    C1         1 5 9

2    C2         9 17 18

3    C3         3 7 11
```

In my application in front end site we have given an option user can select one or more items based on that we have to short list suggested items

For that we have created a column ITEM_ARRAY which keeps information of related ITEMS separated by array.

I need a query to list all ITEM_NAME from ITEM table based on the related ITEMS of CONDITION table. For example if user selects 1 and 9 then we have to display ITEM ID( 5 17 18 ) and their corresponding ITEM NAME. like this.

```
ID |  ITEM_NAME
---+-----------
5  |  SOME ITEM1
17 |  SOME ITEM2
18 |  SOME ITEM3
```

I tried to write a query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(s.ITEM,2, LENGTH(s.ITEM)) 
FROM ( SELECT REPLACE(ITEM_ARRAY," ",",") as ITEM 
       FROM `CONDITION` 
       WHERE ITEM like "% 1 5 %") s
```

above query shows me the list of all related ITEM_ARRAY from CONDITION table if user selects 1 and 5. but if user selects some different values like 1,9 or 1,17,18 kind of ITEMS then my query gets failed to list related items.

How can i get all related values. we are free to make some changes on tables structure without data redundancy.

Please give your valuable suggestions to overcome with the problem. if any other concept like trigger can help us so please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you best option is to re-design the `CONDITION` table so that it doesn't have all ITEM IDs in single ITEM ARRAY - you should have one row per ITEM ID instead. In that case you should normalize the data a bit, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE cond (
 CID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 COND_NAME VARCHAR(128));

CREATE TABLE condition_items (
 CID INT,
 ITEM_ID INT);

INSERT INTO cond VALUES (1,'C1');
INSERT INTO condition_items VALUES (1,1),(1,5),(1,9);

INSERT INTO cond VALUES(2,'C2');
INSERT INTO condition_items VALUES (2,9),(2,17),(2,18);
```

If you are using InnoDB then you could use foreign keys to enforce integrity:

```
ALTER TABLE condition_items ADD FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES cond (CID);
```

This will allow very straightforward JOINs to be performed between the tables.

```
SELECT item_id,item_name 
 FROM cond 
 JOIN condition_items USING (CID) 
 JOIN item ON (item.id=condition_items.item_id) 
 WHERE cond_name="C2";
```

Please note that you should avoid using `CONDITION` as table name as it is reserved word.

Comment: Thanks for answering vhu above structure change have worked for me after a small change in select statement i.e.                                                                 SELECT  ITEM_ID FROM `condition_items` C2 WHERE C2.CID IN(SELECT DISTINCT c.CID as CID FROM `condition_items` c WHERE ITEM_ID IN (5,9,17)). Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your table structure, you should move `ITEM_ARRAY` into its own table.

```
COND_ITEM =>
    COND_ID => INTEGER (foreign key to CONDITION table)
    ITEM_ID => INTEGER (foreign key to ITEM table)
```

Then you can use the query:

```
SELECT ID, ITEM_NAME
FROM ITEM
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT ITEM_ID
    FROM COND_ITEM
    WHERE COND_ID IN (
        SELECT COND_ID
        FROM COND_ITEM
        WHERE ITEM_ID IN (1, 9)
    ) AND ITEM_ID NOT IN (1, 9)
)
```

or a JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.ID, i.ITEM_NAME
FROM ITEM AS i
JOIN COND_ITEM AS ci1 ON ci1.ITEM_ID = i.ID
JOIN COND_ITEM AS ci2 ON ci1.COND_ID = ci2.COND_ID
WHERE ci1.ITEM_ID NOT IN (1, 9)
AND ci2.ITEM_ID IN (1, 9)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9aee1/5)